# Can I restore the window without focusing it?

Tags: java, windows, winapi

As a normal windows user, I rarely distinguish between window being in background and minimised - the effect is usually the same: I don't see it.

But in fact, minimised windows do have client rectangle of zero dimensions. As such, it's impossible to take a screenshot of them. My application needs to take a window screenshot even when it's minimised (actually, ESPECIALLY when it's minimised). I am trying to automate something in background so that I can do other things in the meantime.

My question therefore is: Can I restore the window (make it visible just like if the user just clicked it) BUT immediately put it in the background and DO NOT lose focus of currently used window?

Calling [`ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_RESTORE)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) puts the window in the foreground and interrupts my activity.

```
   //This equals to the ShowWindow call above and put's the window in focus
   test.restore();
   try {
     screenshot = test.screenshot();
   }
   catch(APIError e) {
     System.err.println("No screenshot. Error: "+e);
   }
```

Comment: You seem to be confusing *foreground* and *visible*. The foreground window is the window the user is currently working with. It need not be visible. A visible window is not necessarily the foreground window. Please update your question with established terminology (see [Windows (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632595.aspx)).

Comment: I'm not confusing anything in this case, even though your comment was useful to me in the therms of giving things correct names. I want to make window visible while not putting in foreground.

Comment: This is not generally possible. You will not win the arms race for becoming the really really topmost window. While [SetWindowPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545.aspx) with the right parameters goes a long way, there is no guarantee for success. In general, it is not possible to have an invisible window render itself ([WM_PRINTCLIENT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145217.aspx) helps, but not all windows will handle it). You could try the thumbnail toolbar facilities, but applications will get it wrong, too.

Comment: And why is it not possible to make window *visible* by native system approach (like when I click it in the taskbar) **but** without it also becoming *foreground*? I keep reading and searching the documentation without success. It's, however, possible to "restore" the window on background using `SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE`. But if the window was maximised before being minimised, it will be normal. This is bad for programs like web browser. But maybe, I could `GetForegroundWindow` then `SW_SHOW` and then show the formerly foreground window. But this effect would be visible to me and annoying. Needs test.

Comment: `WM_PRINTCLIENT` will not help in my opinion. What I actually have trouble with is `GetClientRect` not giving any rectangle (I get [0,0,0,0]) **but** returning true like everything was OK. This happens for minimised windows.

Comment: You assume that you are always able to make a window visible by means of user input. That is not correct. Open *Task Manager*, go to *Options* and enable *Always on top*. Now maximize the window. Even though you are still able to make other windows the foreground window, no window besides Task Manager will be visible. The same concepts apply to API calls. You cannot win this game.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70006/discussion-between-tomas-zato-and-iinspectable).

Comment: What if you hide the window, restore or do whatever you want, and then show it?